# can a default.png allows checking of data from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am creating a map application.
1>when the user clicks on the app icon a default.png is shown .
2>my default.png consists of an image and a progress bar.
3>when the default.png loads, the progress bar inside it should start synchronisation of
web service.then it should create or open database on device .
4>Progress bar should validate user information record in database.
5>it should build a  weather map that should have all 37 types of weather available.

i want to know whether all these are possible in progress bar with the loading of default.png in iphone.Please help me in solving this problem

Comment: You know PNG is just an image format and nothing more... right?

Comment: whether a splash screen can do that

Comment: in place of default.png what should i do so that i can do these steps

Comment: If you had a view to act as the splash screen and looks like the launch image, you can do it, no problem. But not with the image itself.

Comment: Keep the splash screen out of it .. show other view just after your splash screen finish  and this view may contain your progress view  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default.png is just a clever psychological trick. It's a stored image which displays instantly while waiting for the rest of the program to start up.

If the stored image (default.png) looks like your normal interface Mr and Mrs Stoopid Hooman think that they are not waiting at all for your app to boot when in actual fact it may be taking a few seconds to do do.

So in answer to your first question. Yes its possible to write C code which will make your app function.

You need to take a screenshot of what you want your user to see including the zero state progress bar the very instant the icon is tapped. The actual animation of the progress bar will not start for a little while after once

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`

fires.

Answer (score 0):

Default.png is a splash image which fill black screen shown when app launch .

if u want to do server operation at the time of Splash screen shows . just create one view Controller which will have same Default.png image . and do server related operation in that view Controller . once Server related operation complete . remove viewController from window hierarchy . and add your main view controller to Window.